# Hold content in stdin for another script to read in

Tags: linux, bash

If I want to write a script(A) such that it will call another script(B) that will read input from stdin, how can I store the content of file to stdin in A, and also call B in A and then B will read in input from stdin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pipe input into a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408649/pipe-input-into-a-script)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pipeline.
For example:
*filecontent*:

```
Michael
```

*scriptA.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

cat filecontent | ./scriptB.sh
```

*scriptB.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Name:" name
echo "Hello, $name"
```

When you run the script scriptA.sh. The output will be:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ./scriptA.sh
Hello, Michael
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your real need but logically it can look like this:

```
# A.sh
cat > /a/tmp/file
/script/to/B < /a/tmp/file
```

If you don't have special requirements then it can simply be:

```
# A.sh
/script/to/B
```

The point is a child process would inherit opened files from its parent process.