# Protecting scripts from errant clobbering

Tags: bash

I spent some time building this handy bash script that accepts input via `stdin`.  I got the idea from the top answer to this question: [Pipe input into a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408649/pipe-input-into-a-script)

However, I did something really dumb.  I typed the following into the terminal:

`echo '{"test": 1}' > ./myscript.sh`

I meant to pipe it `|` to my script instead of redirecting `>` the output of `echo`.

Up until this point in my life, I never accidentally clobbered any file in this manner.  I'm honestly surprised that it took me until today to make this mistake.  :D

At any rate, now I've made myself paranoid that I'll do this again.  Aside from marking the script as read-only or making backup copies of it, is there anything else I can do to protect myself?  Is it a bad practice in the first place to write a script that accepts input from `stdin`?

Comment: What about using `set -o noclobber`?

Comment: I'd argue that the correct answer is to have a good backup system in place -- not just for scripts, but for *everything* you don't want to randomly lose. You can certainly protect against individual types of data loss mistakes, but not against all of them.

Comment: My question is probably too broad given the variety of answers.  I've picked the answer I implemented because I do have version control and a backup plan, but I never thought to toss the scripts in a directory on the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very open-ended question, but I usually put scripts in a global bin folder (`~/.bin` or so). This lets me invoke them as `myscript` rather than `path/to/myscript.sh`, so if I accidentally used `>` instead of `|`, it'd just create a file by that name in the current directory - which is virtually never `~/.bin`.

Comment: Yes the root of my problem, aside from the `>`, is I ran the script in the current directory.  Your technique will definitely help.  Executing the bash script without the extension is a bonus in this case!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is one thing you can do -- check your scripts into a source-code-control repository (git, svn, etc).

bash scripts are code, and any non-trivial code you write should be checked in to source-code-control (and changes committed regularly) so that when something like this happens, you can just restore the most-recently-committed version of the file and continue onwards.