# Piping Text into a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, oracle

When my User logs in, I need to enter the following manually so I am trying to create a script to do it for me

```
. oraenv
```

The app asks me for input so I enter "M40" (same text every time)

Then I have to run a linux app to launch my work environment.

So how do I automatically enter M40 followed by an enter key

Comment: This might work: `echo "M40" | . oraenv`

Answer (score 3):

The `oraenv` script is prompting for a value for `ORACLE_SID`, so you can set that yourself in a `.profile` or elsewhere.

```
export ORACLE_SID=M40
```

It also has a flag you can set to make it non-interactive:

```
ORAENV_ASK=NO
```

Regarding piped input specifically, the script would have to be written to handle it, for example using `read` or commands such as `cat` without a filename. See [Pipe input into a script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19408649/230471) for more details. However, this is not how the standard `oraenv` is coded (assuming that is the script you are using).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if anyone of these operations helps you.

```
echo M40 | . oraenv
```

This one uses `echo` pipe.

```
printf M40 | . oraenv
```

This one uses `printf` for pipe. Using `echo` is different from using `printf` in some situations, however I don't know their actual difference.

```
. oraenv <<< M40
```

This one uses [Here String](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) (Sorry for using ABS as reference), a stripped-down form of [Heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).

```
. oraenv < <(echo M40)
```

This one uses [Process Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html), you may see https://superuser.com/questions/1059781/what-exactly-is-in-bash-and-in-zsh for the difference between this one and the above one.

```
expect -c "spawn . oraenv; expect \"nput\"; send \"M40\r\n\"; interact"
```

This one uses [`expect`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) to do automatic input, it has more extensibility in many situations. Note to change the `expect \"nput\"` part with your actual situation.

Comment: `expect` won't work because `spawn` creates a new process and even if you could execute `.` (expect will try to execute your current directory) it cannot change the environment (which is what the script probably does)