# Pipe output from process executed by mono

Tags: bash, mono

Using the `mono` CLI on Linux, I am trying to find a way to pipe stdout to a script (or equivalent). The example below shows the spirit of what I meant but it doesn't work. From what I can tell, the script `myscript.sh` is never executed.

In the example below, `netframeworkapp.exe` is a long running .NET Framework process being run in Mono on Ubuntu. When run in a console on Windows, it constantly writes output to the console. On Windows, I can pipe that output to Power shell cmdlets. If possible, I want to pipe the output in the bash shell to `myscript.sh` for processing. Also, my script.sh is tested with a mock script and does correctly read stdin; it just seems to not get anything from `mono`.

```sh
#!/etc/bash

mono netframeworkapp.exe | my script.sh
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pipe input into a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408649/pipe-input-into-a-script)

Comment: @SushiHangover No but thanks. I forgot to mention I do know how to read stdin in myscript.sh. The problem is my script.sh isn't getting executed when piping from Mono. (I know my script works because I tested it with a mock script that just echoes data in the proper format.)